# Multiline scrollable textbox inside of Telerik for WPF RadGanttView control

Tags: wpf, textbox, telerik

I'm trying to make a GanttView with scrollable multiline text field for notes about tasks. I made a custom DataTemplate, which is applied in code-behind, since this column needs to be hiddable.

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MemoCellTemplate">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FormattedValue}"
                     IsReadOnly="False"
                     TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     MaxLines="5"/>
        </DataTemplate>
```

```
var memoCellTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["MemoCellTemplate"];

var binding = new Binding
{
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
    Path = new PropertyPath("DynamicProperty." + name)
};

var newColumn = new Telerik.Windows.Controls.GanttView.ColumnDefinition
{
    MemberBinding = binding,
    CellTemplate = memoCellTemplate,
};
```

I faced two problems:

1. In case of long text, GanttView row adjusts its height to fit whole text, while TextBox actually shows 5 lines, as desired
   [Cell with a long note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RpNp.png)
2. Mouse wheel scrolls all GanttView instead of TextBox's content even if cursor is above TextBox.

For row height I tried to set CellContainer's MaxHeight by using a style, but this is not a good option since font size in my app can be changed.

For scrolling I tried to use a bool flag which is set in TextBox_MouseEnter and TextBox_MouseLeave event handlers and which forces GanttView_MouseWheel to break, but with no result